# How to create an Objective-C project in an old version

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios6

I have to create an application with a minimum version in iOS 6.0 and Objective-C.

How can I create a new project in that version? 
I've tried creating a normal project and switching to iOS 6 later, but it gives me a lot of errors.

Can an application in iOS 6 be seen correctly on a terminal with notch?

Comment: With Xcode 10.2 & 11.x you can give backward compatibility upto ios8. And you need to add lots of iOS API checks.

Comment: You are going to have issues with distribution unless you distribute the app with an enterprise developer certificate. I don't think the appStore accepts lower targets than ios 8 now.

Comment: If your target is 6.0. You need to face issues to satisfy new devices. You need to check every API with device version. It's better to avoid. But if it your requirement, then design, UI programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create an application with a minimum version in iOS 6.0.
AppStore won't accept your application. Most of old frameworks are deprecated and no longer supported by new iOS versions.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to get versions of MACOS and XCode that supported IOS6.0
That would be `OS X Yosemite` and `XCode 6` or `7`.

You can install the old MACOS on a virtual machine or better download a Virtual Machine of older MACOS.

Be aware: Old versions of MACOS,XCode may not be secure and you will have to download from websites other than apple.

Comment: Or, you know, you could use https://developer.apple.com/download/more/